# Combining two indexes from a list

Tags: python

I have a list called cleaned_text

```
cleaned_text = ['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machine', 'gun', 'behind', 'him']
```

I want to combine the words 'machine' and 'gun' to be as follows:

```
cleaned_text = ['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machinegun', 'behind', 'him']
```

I am using whats below to run a loop to check the code, however I cannot seem to combine the indexes of `value` and `next_idx`

```
def white_space_problem(cleaned_text):
    for next_idx, value in enumerate(cleaned_text[:-1], 1):
        if value == 'machine' and cleaned_text[next_idx] == 'gun':
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the index using the index function, then change the value of the list in those indexes to the wanted result:

```
cleaned_text = ['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machine', 'gun', 'behind', 'him']
idx = cleaned_text.index('machine')
cleaned_text[idx:idx+2] = [''.join(cleaned_text[idx:idx+2])]
print(cleaned_text)
```

**Result:**

`['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machinegun', 'behind', 'him']`

If you have more than one `'machine'` value or/and more than one `'machine gun'` pare, you can use this instead:

```
cleaned_text = ['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the','machine', 'gun', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machine', 'gun', 'behind', 'him']
last_gun_idx = cleaned_text[::-1].index('gun') *-1-1
while cleaned_text[last_gun_idx] == 'gun':
    idx= cleaned_text.index('machine')
    while cleaned_text[idx+1] != 'gun':
        idx = cleaned_text[idx+1:].index('machine') + idx + 1
    cleaned_text[idx:idx+2] = [''.join(cleaned_text[idx:idx+2])]
    print(cleaned_text)
```

Note that it won't work if there is a `'gun'` not after `'machine'`

Comment: This is a nice use of slicing, but only works with a single replacement

Comment: OK but at a very expensive cost, `while 'gun' in cleaned_text` is O(n) at each step, so is `list.index`, so the worst complexity is quite bad ;)

Comment: Now it is a bit better :)

Answer (score 0):

One option with a loop:

```
cleaned_text = ['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machine', 'gun', 'behind', 'him']

out = []
skip = False
for t in zip(cleaned_text, cleaned_text[1:]+[None]):
    if skip:
        skip = False
        continue
    if t == ('machine', 'gun'):
        out.append('machinegun')
        skip = True
    else:
        out.append(t[0])
        
out
```

Output:

```
['#bullhornlady', 'in', 'the', 'same', 'pic', 'with', 'the', 'same', 'horn', 'guess', 'this', 'pic', 'is', 'how', '#eyegouger', 'got', 'his', 'designation', 'i', 'see', 'a', 'machinegun', 'behind', 'him']
```

##### how it works

This is probably very similar to what a human works be doing, check the words one after the other and merge when is finds a matching pair. The complexity is O(n) (i.e. best possible complexity assuming you need to read all values). It works for any number of substitutions.

Algorithm:

- for each pair of values (n, n+1)
- if you have a machine+gun pair

  - add machinegun and skip next word
- else, add first word
- repeat with the next pair (n+1, n+2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the current index to modify the list in place. You can do this by not starting the enumeration at index 1 and just checking your next index with a +1. then to combine the 2 items you can pop the next index which will return the value and remove it from the list. then concat the current value and next value at the current index.

```
for idx, value in enumerate(cleaned_text[:-1]):
  if value == 'machine' and cleaned_text[idx + 1] == 'gun':
         cleaned_text[idx] = value + cleaned_text.pop(idx + 1)
```

Comment: It is best not to change a list while iterating through it.